# i7 2600 compatibility with PCIe 3?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, gpu, pci-express

My motherboard and graphics card died recently and I was thinking of buying the ASRock Z75 Pro3 and R9 280X. I think that my i7-2600 (because it is Sandy Bridge)is not compatible with PCIe-3 which the motherboard has the R9 280x have.

I know that the R9 280x works in PCIe-2 ports (which the motherboard has) but I don't know if it will work if I plug it into the PCIe-3 port on the motherboard.

Hope you understand what I am asking?

Will a PCIe-3 GPU (R9 280X) work in a PCIe-3 port with a CPU (i7-2600) that does not support PCIe-3.

Answer (score 0):

No, [PCIe 3 only works with at least an Ivy Bridge CPU](http://www.techpowerup.com/144801/ivy-bridge-cpus-feature-pci-express-3-0.html) (3xxx). Your Sandy Bridge only support 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It will work at PCI 2.0 Speeds, but that should be enough to run the video card at its full potential on a x16 slot I believe. The ports are electrically identical, and it will work.